# What is the correct cipher name for RC4 in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, https

I want to [remove RC4 from Google Chrome](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/38493/158) and found the commandline option `--cipher-suite-blacklist`. However I wasn't able to figure out what the correct notation for RC4 is. Whatever I tried so far only brought the message:

```
ERROR:ssl_config_service_manager_pref.cc(55)] Ignoring unrecognized or \
  unparsable cipher suite:
```

Even the names listed in `ssl_cipher_suite_names.cc` don't work. What should I enter to remove RC4 as a cipher for SSL/TLS?

I'm working with some different versions of GNU/Linux and sometimes also with Windows. So it would be nice if the command-line argument would work under all OSes. I used the following command:

```
chrome --cipher-suite-blacklist=TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 --ssl-version-min=tls1.1
chrome --cipher-suite-blacklist=RC4 --ssl-version-min=tls1.1
chrome --cipher-suite-blacklist=0xXYZ,0xUVW --ssl-version-min=tls1.1  # XYZ and UVW are some hexadecimal numbers
```

Comment: whats your OS? I assume you are trying commands from this page? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58831 what was the exact command you entered?

Comment: Yes, I try the commands from this page as well as the linked IANA page.

Comment: what was your command exactly, and did you attempt to quote the argument containing the slash?

Comment: I'm playing around with Google Chrome and also with Chromium and have to double-check if they both use the same command-line args.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must inform the ciphers in hex based in RFC 2246 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt).

The correct command line is:

```
 chrome --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0004,0x0005,0xc011
```

No spaces between comma.

Comment: This works, but I don't see from your link and answer how you decided to add the (necessary) option `0xc011`. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: @gentmatt See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4 for a list of all cipher suites. You can ignore the anonymous, export, PSK and KRB5 cipher suites as they are not used. 0xC011 is TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA. Missing RC4 cipher suites in this list are 0xC002,0xC007,0xC00C.

Answer (score 2):

Tiago is right.

However, there are some more ciphers You may want to block:
https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55163.44/libsecurity_ssl/Security/CipherSuite.h?txt

Consequently, you should try this command line:

> chrome --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0001,0x0002,0x0004,0x0005,0x0017,0x0018,0xc002,0xc007,0xc00c,0xc011,0xc016,0xff80,0xff81,0xff82,0xff83

It should block all ciphers using RC4 and/or MD5.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You need to add the following parameter to block all RC4 ciphers (as of Chrome 31 in Ubuntu 12.04 with NSS 3.15)

```
--cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0004,0x0005,0xc011,0xc007
```

### General Answer to figure it out yourself

The regularly updated [list of all ciphers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) by **IANA** which user @Lekensteyn [posted](https://superuser.com/questions/616996/what-is-the-correct-cipher-name-for-rc4-in-chrome#comment849864_618221) is already very helpful and definitely better than skimming some [`.txt`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) files, but I have found an even easier way to...

- check what ciphers your browser supports
- get the hexadecimal value of the supported ciphers

Both information is provided directly in your browser by visiting the following website of the Leibniz University of Hannover:

- https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/

In the picture below, the cipher indentifiers on are on the left side of the table. So, if I wanted to block the two ciphers `RSA-AES-128-GCM-SHA256` and `RSA-AES256-SHA` I would look for `(00,9c)` and `(00,35)`.

For Google Chrome this means that I have to add the parameter<sup>1</sup>:

```
--cipher-suite-blacklist=0x009c,0x0035
```

[image]

__

**1-** In Google Chrome on Ubuntu you have to edit the file `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and add the parameter to each line that starts with `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`. There should be three overall.

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x009c,0x0035
```